# UINavigationController Back Button position

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, ios

Ist it possible to set the back button of UINavigationController to the right side programatically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create a custom button and place in on the right hand side. You could assign an action to the button which performs your going back functionality.

The problem with this is that your back button wouldn't have the look and feel of the traditional back button that users have come to expect, and your app may be rejected for going against this very common user interface design.

Comment: But I would have to re-implement all the hiding/showing logic, right? How likely would you think is it that the app gets rejected?

Comment: You don't have to re-implement the hiding/showing logic because you can simply manipulate the UINavigationController's view stack (check the reference page for the methods needed to do this). I couldn't say how likely it is that it'd get rejected. Try think about why you're trying to go against the convential back button. If you've got good reasons then I guess you're less likely to be rejected.